# LINQPad throws NullReferenceException on valid code

Tags: c#, events, delegates, nullreferenceexception, linqpad

I'm [reading about C# events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx), and I'd like to copy and paste the following code into LINQPad and run it:

```
class Test
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("add operation");
        }

        remove
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("remove operation");
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();

        t.MyEvent += new EventHandler (t.DoNothing);
        t.MyEvent -= null;
    }

    void DoNothing (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I am importing the `System` namespace in Query Properties.

I can't figure out why LINQPad throws a `NullReferenceException`:

```
Message Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Data    Data
InnerException  (null)
TargetSite  TargetSite
StackTrace     at LINQPad.ExecutionModel.ClrQueryRunner.Run()
   at LINQPad.ExecutionModel.Server.RunQuery(QueryRunner runner)
HelpLink    null
Source  LINQPad
HResult -2147467261
```

The same code compiles just fine if I create a project in Visual Studio, which is what I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your main method out of the class like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Test t = new Test();

    t.MyEvent += new EventHandler (t.DoNothing);
    t.MyEvent -= null;
}

class Test
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("add operation");
        }

        remove
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("remove operation");
        }
    }

    public void DoNothing (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

This is a limitation of LinqPad.

Cheers

Comment: It'd be great if it told you as much.

Comment: Right. I just happened to remember seeing that one at some point, but the docs are scarce on the subject.